# What is the default file system of /var/run, /var/lock

Tags: filesystem, mount, tmpfs

Trying to figure out if my /var/run is using disk or not. See the command output:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-root   40G   15G   26G  36% /
none                  3.9G  340K  3.9G   1% /dev
none                  3.9G  1.1M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 3.9G  600K  3.9G   1% /tmp
none                  3.9G  452K  3.9G   1% /var/run
none                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /var/lock
none                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/md0              236M   59M  165M  27% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-home   60G   58G  2.3G  97% /home
```

Comment: sorry, i figured this out later. answer is posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all `tmpfs` file systems. Using `-T` shows the file system type:

```
$ df -hT
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-root
          reiserfs     40G   15G   26G  36% /
none      devtmpfs    3.9G  340K  3.9G   1% /dev
none         tmpfs    3.9G  1.1M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.9G  680K  3.9G   1% /tmp
none         tmpfs    3.9G  452K  3.9G   1% /var/run
none         tmpfs    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /var/lock
none         tmpfs    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/md0      ext3    236M   59M  165M  27% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-home
          reiserfs     60G   58G  2.3G  97% /home
```